# Apache RewriteRule - Can't remove "index.php?q="

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm testing .htaccess file on the server. The goal is to convert `www.mysite.com/index.php?q=help` into `mysite.com/help`

1)to remove `www.` 
2) to remove `index.php?q=`

My .htaccess in the root directory contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Nothing happens - index.php?q=help is still there...
Does anybody know, why?

Thank you.

Matthew, thanks again. Here is another version, the problem solved for 50%.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301] #removes www., works fine 
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ http://mysite.com/ [NC,R,L] #still doesn't work - it does not remove index.php as needed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original request will still be there due to RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: Actually, my comment was probably bad advice, you should leave it back in there.  If you leave it out, then that means that every file should direct to index.php?q=, which you obviously don't want in the case of images/css/js files.

Comment: comment moved to the question because of readability. Question solved for 50%. Still looking for an answer about removing index.php

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to do what you're asking.

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]

however, mysite.com/index.php?q=mypage and mysite.com/mypage will both go to the same page.  Is that really an issue though, if people don't know that the index.php file exists, then they wouldn't be typing it in.  Or are you trying to change an existing live server?